# Glassfish 4 DAS start failed

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

I did  a clean eclipse install (Java EE Juno SR2)
I Installed GlassFish Tools (5.2.2.201305090916)

Installed Glassfish 4 with the wizard.

If i try to start it with eclipse I get a simple error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching GlassFish 4.0 at localhost".
DAS start failed.
```

No log available

but I can start the server without any problems with the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Eclipse, but if it is using "asadmin" to start GF4 try to te,mporarily add the the "--verbose" option.  It will show errors that occur before the logging is setup.  E.g. jvm errors, OSGi errors.
The process will "hang" as far as eclipse is concerned though.